# stop application with TIMER AND TIMERTASK

Tags: timer, timertask

I am doing my app on android, when I run my application I can see the screen but when I give click show the message "THE APLICATION STOP", when i give click automatically run each time a random where the number that shown a color. I am using `Timer` and `TimerTask`.

```
public class HolaMundo extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView fondoImg;
    Button entrada;
    int valorfinal;
    TimerTask tareatiempo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hola_mundo);
        fondoImg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fondoPantalla);
        entrada=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEncen);
        final Timer tarea=new Timer();

        entrada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tareatiempo = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        busqueda();
                    }
                };
                tarea.scheduleAtFixedRate(tareatiempo,0,5000);

            }
        });
    }
    public void busqueda()
    {
         valorfinal=(int)(Math.random()*4+1);
        switch (valorfinal)
        {
            case 1:
                fondoImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.amarillo);
                break;
            case 2:
                fondoImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.negro);
                break;
            case 3:
                fondoImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.rojo);
                break;
            case 4:
                fondoImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.verde);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can see the screen but when I give click show the message "THE APLICATION STOP"

Comment: You should see a stack trace in your console. It will look like [this](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/attachment/12354395/eclipse%20stack%20trace.png?_sscc=t). It would be helpful to see that stack trace.